# How to create image download link in smarty

Tags: smarty

I need to create a download link, On click on which the image will get download.

Am new to smarty and tried few of the option with html by searching on google.
Below are the code I tried but this seems to be of no use.

```
<a href="{image_url}" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a href="{image_url}" download="myImage">Download image</a>
<a href="/var/www/file/attachment/{destination}" target="_blank">Download link</a>
```

It will be really help full if anyone can help me or guide me on how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Smarty can't do that. However, you can use the html download attribute, that will force the download:

```
<a href="{image_url}" target="_blank" download>Download</a>
```

Unfortunately it only works in the most recent browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

So if you want it to work everywhere, you'll have to use a server side solution, i.e. using a php script:

```
 <a href="dowload.php?file={image_url}">
```

or forcing the download with htaccess